# After updating Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 1, i got error Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I got error of "Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'"

`Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

My mac is intel so M1 is not the problem.
I tried so many suggestions on stack overflow. but i still can't find the answer,,,,

My gradle JDK is 17.0.6

== remove code that i have uploaded a part of gradle files ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was Android Studio JDK version and my Java version was different•••

after upgrading Android Studio, its JDK version sets to JDK 17. but, my Java version is still 14.0.1. So, I set both in the same version.

That's why i stuck in build error,,! so,, stupid,,,

anyway i hope someone to solve this kind of problem easily!

```
check in terminal : java -version

check the JDK version in Android Studio : settings > Build > Gradle > 'Gradle JDK'
```

Comment: I appreciate this.. I started developing on Mac a few weeks ago when my windows laptop died. So after transferring everything to Mac I ran into the same issue. I will have to check this out later to see if it helps.

Comment: @CampNerd if your mac is m1, then add `kapt "org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0"` this in your app gradle. I saw many this error cases with m1 mac user and they solved it by adding that line.

Comment: my Mac is a mid 2012 running Catalina. I just moved to Mac because my windows died and having to replace the motherboard. My biggest issue is after moving everything over from Win to Mac I updated everything and this was the only issue. I have apps on Google Play I need to update in the mean time until I get a new Mac if they ever decide which M to go with. M3 is hitting the market M2 discounted and M1 I guess is the stable one. So I just need to update my apps in the mean time